# JavaScript RegExp not working in IE11 and working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-11

I have created the following `RegExp` object:

```
RegExp(/_if|_elseif|_else|_while|_store/, "g")
```

I need to match either of the pipe delim strings. The above method works in chrome. But the IE11 throws error saying some syntax error.

Answer (score 12):

That's because the `RegExp` constructor in IE11 only takes a *string* as its first argument, and not a regular expression literal:

```
RegExp("_if|_elseif|_else|_while|_store", "g")
       ^                               ^
```

Alternatively, you can simply add the `g` flag to the end of your regular expression literal and drop the constructor notation altogether:

```
/_if|_elseif|_else|_while|_store/g
```